# MVC 5 Layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC site, and I use the same "_layout page" for all the view.
In _layout page, I have a select control.

What I want is to read the selected value of the control from the other pages.

Can you help me understand how to do?

Edit:
**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="slt_Aziende">Azienda:</label>
    <select id="mySharedSelectControl">
        <option value="1">value 1</option>
        <option value="2">value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtlm** (using _Layout.cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<MySite.Models.MyModel>
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**MyModelController**

```
public class MyModelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {        
        //get value from mySharedSelectControl from Layout page
       var selectedValueFromLayoutPage;

       //do something
      return View();   
   }
}
```

Comment: You want yo read value by javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly read value of `controls` in `Controller`, you need to send the value of `dropdown` to the `controller` and than process what you want.

Or you can directly read value of `dropdown` from JavaScript in other `views` and do your processing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Mairaj said is right i.e you can't directly read values of controls in your controller.

What you can do is create a JavaScript function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mySharedSelectControl").change(function () {
                var dropdownValue = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("PutValueinSession", "MyModel")", //Action method on which you want to send this dropdown value
                    data: { id: dropdownValue },
                    success: function (e) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

You can create a method in which you can put this value in session and used across your whole page like below:

```
public JsonResult PutValueinSession(int id)
        {
            Session["DropdownControlValue"] = id;
            return Json(new { Result = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Now you can access this value on any page:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {        
        //get value from mySharedSelectControl from Layout page
       var selectedValueFromLayoutPage=Session["DropdownControlValue"];

       //do something
      return View();   
   }
```